# Calendarview OnselectedDayChange to Timestamp

Tags: android, timestamp, calendarview

I'm trying to create an app that has a calendar in it. Once the user chooses a date and clicks ok button, I want the chosen date to be saved in my Firestore database as a timestamp.

Im trying to use:

```
calendarView = findViewById( R.id.cv_BorrowCalendar );
calendarView.setOnDateChangeListener(new CalendarView.OnDateChangeListener() {
    @Override
    public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView arg0, int year, int month, int date) {
        Log.d("", "DATE : " + date);
    }
});
```

This code returns only the data I choose like 1st ,4th,31st.

I tried also to use `arg0.getDate()` but it returns the current date and not the selected date.

Is there a way to translate the chosen date to timestamp?

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, millis contains the timestamp:

```
 @Override
 public void onSelectedDayChange(CalendarView arg0, int year, int month, int date) {
    GregorianCalendar cal = new GregorianCalendar(year, month, date);
    long millis = cal.getTimeInMillis();
 }
```